# .appxbundle cannot modify the registry

Tags: c#, windows-10, registry, desktop-bridge

I have this simple piece of code, adding my application to run when windows start. Works fine.

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rk.SetValue("my_app", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Then I package it with a Windows Application Packaging Project, connect it to windows store, choose "Create App Packages.." and get the resulting .appxbundle. 
Fine so far. I install it locally. (also installing the generated certificate (.cer) so I can install it at all.)

Once I start the installed app and click a button running the code above, nothing changes in the registry! It does not crash, I have a try..catch around the code. It just silently ignore it.

Running it from visual studio works fine, the registry gets updated.

Actually, all I want is the app to start when windows start, I am not particularly interested in how to achieve that, so any ideas are welcome!

---

Edit: I forgot to say the most important stuff: It is a Windows Desktop, Windows Forms App. It is not a UWP app, but a window inheriting an ordinary System.Windows.Forms.Form, compiled with x86.

Xavier mentions the StartupTask extension, it's a nuget package but it seems to be used when you have a UWP app.

Comment: I am trying to follow the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask, but I don't even know in which file to put the <Applications> part...

Answer (score 3):

> Actually, all I want is the app to start when windows start, I am not particularly interested in how to achieve that, so any ideas are welcome!

You need to use the `windows.startupTask` Extension for your packaged UWP app. Please see [Start an executable file when users log into Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#start-an-executable-file-when-users-log-into-windows). With this extension, you can start your app whenever a user logs on.

> Please note: The user has to start your application at least one time to register this startup task.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say: It is a Windows Desktop, Windows Forms App, so it's not a UWP app.

Comment: @Snorvarg You said 'Then I package it with a Windows Application Packaging Project'. After you packaged it, it's a UWP app.

Comment: Yikes, it just means I don't understand it.. I tried that package, installed it as a nuget. But the code examples are for the UWP namespaces.

Comment: I have been following this guide so far, it works until my application wants to change the registry: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Comment: @Snorvarg I suggested you to read 'registry' relevant sections on [Prepare to package](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) and [Behind the scenes of the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#registry).